# Can I force/trick sp_describe_first_result_set to return is_nullable = 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries that return the same result schema. One has a "group by" and so column values are aggregate functions (MAX, SUM), but the column names and underlying data types are the same.

My problem is that when I run sp_describe_first_result_set, NOT NULL cols in the simple query are described as is_nullable 0, whereas aggregate functions on these same cols have is_nullable = 1. Even if I do COALESCE(MAX(myCol),0), this is still gives is_nullable 1.

FIX: Is there something I can do to make my aggregate cols appear as is_nullable 0 ?
or WORKAROUND: Is there some performance-neutral change that will make not-nullable cols in the first query report as nullable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Comparing `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#comparing-coalesce-and-isnull):

> The NULLability of the result expression is different for ISNULL and
>   COALESCE. The ISNULL return value is always considered NOT NULLable
>   (assuming the return value is a non-nullable one). By
>   contrast,COALESCE with non-null parameters is considered to be NULL.
>   So the expressions ISNULL(NULL, 1) and COALESCE(NULL, 1), although
>   equal, have different nullability values.

```
select IsNull( Max( Foo ), -2147483648 ) as MaxFoo, ...
```

will do the trick.

NB: Be sure to use an appropriate default value.